# How can there be no largest number in an interval set?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

The question I have is:

***Given the interval $[1,3)$, explain why there is no largest number in this set.***

I don't understand how that interval set does not have a largest number. I know what this means and when you draw it.

I watched my lecture and read through all the notes and everything, but being an online class I'm taking, it makes it a bit more difficult for me.

Comment: Hint: if the number $x$ is in this set, then so is average of $x$ and $3$.

Comment: It should be mentioned that $3$ will be the [supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) of the set, but supremums need not be elements of the sets themselves.  Your intuition might be telling you "$3$ is the largest number" but remember that $3$ is not in the set, it is outside of it.

Comment: @JMoravitz You're right, i kept thinking that 3 is in the set. But it indeed isnt because 1 <= x < 3. So it can be anything up to 3. Therefore making an infinite amount of decimal points greater than the previous. 

That actually makes sense to me now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I would argue by saying that no matter what number $x$ I consider in the interval, I can always find a larger number in that interval. Thus there can be no largest number in the interval.

Assume that $x$ is a number in the interval $[1,3)$. Since $x$ is contained in the interval, we must have $x<3$.

Set $y = x+\frac{3-x}{2}$. Then since $3>x$, we have that $\frac{3-x}{2}>0$, and thus $y>x$. I claim that $y$ is also contained in the interval $[1,3)$.

Indeed, we have $y = x+\frac{3-x}{2} = \frac{2x+(3-x)}{2} = \frac{x+3}{2}<\frac{3+3}{2} = 3$, and thus $y<3$.